# CSS Why width is wrong?

Tags: css

I have a web page as follows (see img)

A certain div has a width of 100% which is filling the whole viewport.

When checking on Chrome, the viewport size is 500px while the CSS size is 536.

Does anyone have an idea why it's different please ?

Thanks.
Cheers,

[image]

Comment: what if you check the width of its ancestor/s? (also note that `100% != 100vw`)

Comment: an overflow probably

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many modern visualization techniques, such as parallax, require larger elements than the actual viewport size and a smart usage of `transform` properties in order to create particular visual effects and/or illusions.

Your picture is actually showing a part of the parent element displaying properties particular to such techniques, clearly showing: `-webkit-logical-width:800px` and `perspective-origin: 400px 300px`.

For any element with a `position` value other than `fixed`, `width:100%` usually results into the child having an equal `width` with the parent, not with the viewport. There are notable exceptions from this rule, though.

If you need a more in-depth explanation as to why does the parent have a different width than the viewport (and it's parent parent, and so on... - all the way to the viewport), you need to post a [Minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I'll lay down each of the ancestors of your element affecting its `width`.

If, on the contrary, you don't really need to know what's going on at parents level, but are looking for a way to make your current element as wide as the viewport, you probably want to give it a width value of `100vw`.